# Using compare and set against multiple expected values with AtomicReference

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

I have a bit of a unique situation. I'd like to be able to use the `compareAndSet()` feature of `AtomicReference` but with a bit of a twist.

Normally you use `compareAndSet()` to compare against a single, expected value before you actually change it. In my case the expected value to compare against could be one of many values.

Is there a way to do this using `AtomicReference`? If not, what other techniques should I use? Perhaps just traditional use of `synchronized`?

Comment: Compare and swap requires hardware support, so I don't think you can chain them together to get the behavior you want.  `synchronized` is probably safer.  However, look up "lock free linked list", it is possible to design around the problem, but it's darned complex.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you have a `Set` of expected values.  In that case...

```
<T> boolean setIfInExpected(AtomicReference<T> ref, Set<?> expected, T newValue) {
  while (true) {
    T current = ref.get();
    if (set.contains(current)) {
      if (atomicReference.compareAndSet(current, newValue)) {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

This is typical for how uses of `compareAndSet` work: they run in a loop until the `AtomicReference` doesn't change between the `get` and the `compareAndSet`.

Comment: Depending on the context, a simple `return set.contains(current) && atomicReference.compareAndSet(current, newValue);` might be sufficient, it depends on how contention ought be handled for the particular use case.